# Unable to connect to cosmos db emulator Mongo API 3.6

Tags: python, pymongo, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, azure-emulator

I am able to connect to the standard MongoAPI 3.2 version with python as well as Robo 3T after executing the startup with the following:

`CosmosDb.Emulator.exe /EnableMongoDbEndpoint`

However when starting the emulator with:

`CosmosDb.Emulator.exe /EnableMongoDbEndpoint=3.6`

I am no longer able to connect with python, only with Robo 3T. I have tried adding a mongoport param and referencing the generated cert with pymongo and but to no avail

```
import pymongo

from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure

uri = 'mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5%2FR%2Bob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM%2B4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw%2FJw%3D%3D@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE&retrywrites=false'
try:
    # The is master command is cheap and does not require auth.
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(uri)
    print(client.admin.command('ismaster'))
except ConnectionFailure:
    print("Server not available")
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?